# MSBuild ignores AndroidVersionCode

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, xamarin.android, msbuild, azure-pipelines

As the [doc stands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-properties#androidversioncode), one can define `-p:AndroidVersionCode=101` as one of MSBuild arguments.

However, the Android Version Code is ignored and the final APK file always contains only the value from AndroidManifest.xml even though the `<GenerateApplicationManifest>true</GenerateApplicationManifest>` is defined in the `*Droid.csproj` file (in fact, I've set it also in netstandard csfile).

How to define Version Code for MSBuild?

Here is the complete MSBuild command which I use:

`msbuild -t:Clean -t:PackageForAndroid -p:AndroidPackageFormat=apk -p:ApplicationVersion="1.0" -p:AndroidVersionCode=101 -p:ApplicationId="cz.sebastian.myapp" -p:OutputPath="C:\Packages\" -p:Configuration=Release .\MyApp.Droid.csproj`

Answer (score 1):

After several practical experiments I've found the following:

1. **Docs are wrong.** The property `AndroidVersionCode` doesn't reflect Android's Version Code, in fact, I didn't find what it's really used for. Version Code can be modified via the `ApplicationVersion` property, only.
2. To really change the Version Code one must remove the `android:versionCode` from `AndroidManifest.xml`.

To sum up: Remove `android:versionCode` from Android manifest and use `ApplicationVersion` with an integer value.

`MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET Framework`

Comment: According to [One .NET "Single Project"](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/OneDotNetSingleProject.md), $(ApplicationVersion) maps to android:versionCode.  Seems they are the same.

Comment: And also refer to [[One .NET] prefer /manifest/@android:versionCode](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/6383), versionCode might be overwritten by a default value.

Comment: Thanks for the links @LiqunShen-MSFT, honestly speaking my impression was that One .NET or Single project always refers to the .NET MAUI and as an evolution of Xamarin I took it as not relevant to Xamarin. I didn't expect that an increment would have such an impact on the stable product (honestly speaking I've started with MAUI template, but there are so many bugs right now, that I wasn't able to finish the app, so I went back to Xamarin - better the devil you know than the devil you don't )